# How replicate Texture2d.LoadImage for png to get RGB32 format (now getting ARGB32)

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, textures, texture2d, loadimage

I am trying to improve performance for the code I use to convert a png to grayscale.

I load image via Json, convert to texture, then grayscale at runtime going through each pixel and using `GetPixels32/SetPixels32`. Memory use is too high for the many images I have so I'd like to use more efficient `GetRawTextureData`.

However `LoadImage` is returning a **ARGB32** `texture2d` which seems to be messing up then follow on use in `GetRawTextureData` (**RGB32**).

It's confusing because png with LoadImage on Unity 2019.2 should be returning [RGBA32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html?_ga=2.51730155.337819668.1576700184-901831458.1542692665) but for me it's returning [ARGB32](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html?_ga=2.51730155.337819668.1576700184-901831458.1542692665) which is what LoadImage legacy Unity 5.3 would have returned - not sure if a bug or documentation error.

```
Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
byte[] t = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);//png image in string format
thisTexture.LoadImage(t);//Using Unity2019.2.2 result is ARGB32
```

When I convert image to grayscale I get a yellowish image and I think that's because `GetRawTextureData` is **RGB32** but `LoadImage` returns **ARGB32**.

How can I replicate the `LoadImage` process to get **RGB32**?

```
//convert texture
        graph = thisTexture;
        grayImg = new Texture2D(graph.width, graph.height, graph.format, false);

        Debug.Log("grayImg format " + grayImg.format + " graph format " + graph.format);
        Graphics.CopyTexture(graph, grayImg);
        var data = grayImg.GetRawTextureData<Color32>();

        int index = 0;
        Color32 pixel;
        for (int x = 0; x < grayImg.width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < grayImg.height; y++)
            {
                pixel = data[index];
                int p = ((256 * 256 + pixel.r) * 256 + pixel.b) * 256 + pixel.g;
                int b = p % 256;
                p = Mathf.FloorToInt(p / 256);
                int g = p % 256;
                p = Mathf.FloorToInt(p / 256);
                int r = p % 256;
                byte l = (byte) ((pixel.r ) + pixel.g + pixel.b);
                Color32 c = new Color32(pixel.r, pixel.g, pixel.b, 1);
                data[index++] = c;
            }
        }
        // upload to the GPU
        grayImg.Apply(false);
```

Revised code with LoadRawTextureData:

```
    Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    byte[] t = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);//png image in string format
    thisTexture.LoadRawTextureData(t);//results in RGBA32 (Note: using either thisTexture.LoadImage(t); or thisTexture.LoadRawTextureData(t); when using LoadRawTextureData to set the pixels on the grayscale, the texture continues to be yellowish.
    thisTexture.Apply();
```

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: Tested building on standalone windows and ios, objective is build on iOS for mobile (ios13 and above) and iPad

Comment: Your code is missing a lot of context. Where do you define changedPixels? Why aren't you using LoadRawTextureData to set the pixels?

Comment: sorry, no changedPixels , i've edited code. Not using changedPixels because this is the version using GetRawTextureData. I didn't know about LoadRawTextureData I'll test now!

Comment: What is your graphics API?

Comment: I've tried LoadRawTextureData and format of texture is now RGBA32 (hurray!) but when running code (edited follow up in main question) I get a blank image (transparent-like)

Comment: Graphics API for iOS is Metal colorGamut sRGB and DisplayP3

Comment: LoadRawTextureData to set the pixels works great from a memory perspective but I still have the yellowish not grayscale texture result.

Comment: I think you are doing the colors in the wrong order, it looks like ARBG instead of ARGB or RGBA

Answer (score 1):

This is not how GetRawTextureData should be used - it retuns NativeArray and those are very slow when mistaken with oridinary array. For examples on this, take a look at this
[RawTextureDataProcessingExamples](https://github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/RawTextureDataProcessingExamples) repo. Especially this [GrayscaleRGBA32Job](https://github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/RawTextureDataProcessingExamples/blob/master/Jobs/GrayscaleRGBA32Job.cs) file:

```
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Collections;

[Unity.Burst.BurstCompile]
public struct GrayscaleRGBA32Job : Unity.Jobs.IJobParallelFor
{
    public NativeArray<RGBA32> data;
    void Unity.Jobs.IJobParallelFor.Execute ( int i )
    {
        var color = data[i];
        float product = math.mul( new float3{ x=color.R , y=color.G , z=color.B } , new float3{ x=0.3f , y=0.59f , z=0.11f } );
        byte b = (byte)product;
        data[i] = new RGBA32{ R=b , G=b , B=b , A=color.A };
    }
}
```

You can swap channel bytes here if you ever need that.
This is how you apply this job:

```
var rawdata = tex.GetRawTextureData<RGBA32>();
new GrayscaleRGBA32Job { data = tex.GetRawTextureData<RGBA32>() }
    .Schedule( rawdata.Length , tex.width ).Complete();
tex.Apply();
```

That's it. Based on this you can also write a job that takes RGBA32 rawData as input and outputs that to grayscale texture's R8 rawData directly (no copy needed, and smaller memory footprint).

Comment: PS: There is no such a format as RGB32, there are RGBA32 and RGB24 however (sometimes also called RGBA8, RGB8).

Comment: If speed is what you're after here then ditch reading image data from strings, text files or whatever that was. Go with raw binary data.